# create a certificate request failed in domino server

Tags: ssl, lotus-domino, ca, certificate-authority

I had a problem when I was setting up a Domino CA so that we can use IBM verse by SSL.

I referred to the IBM redbook about domino certification authority and SSL Certificate and followed it step by step.

I created the certificate authority keyring & certificate, and also created a CA profile in CA.nsf. I then created a key ring and a certificate request in the server certificate admin database, I also copied both .kry and .sth to the domino data directory.

The next step, when I was requesting server certificate in URL site of ca.nsf, I pasted the code from clipboard and pressed the submit button, and then encountered the problem. It returned an error text `certificate signature do not match contents`.

The domino version is 901FP2

The notes version is 901FP6

So, does anybody knows what's happened? How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I think, this question should be moved to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Help is outdated... Please follow [this link for self signed](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Self-signed_SHA-2_with_OpenSSL_and_kyrtool) or [this link for official](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/3rd_Party_SHA-2_with_OpenSSL_and_kyrtool) SSL- certificates. AND: This is the wrong place... goto serverfault with this question

Comment: Thanks for your reminder! I've posed this question on site of [link](http://serverfault.com), but i don't know how to close this question on this  site.